# ConnectionStrings in Web.config for MongoDB Atlas considers <dbname> as un closed tag

Tags: asp.net, web-config, mongodb-atlas

I am working with `MongoDB Atlas` `ConnectionString` which I defined int he `Web.config` for an `ASP.Net` application.

I know that this config file is an XML document hence `&` needs to be replaced by `&amp;`. However, `<dbname>` gotten from `MongoDB Atlas`  connection string shows an error. This is considered as "Tag was not closed". How that can be handled?

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="conn" connectionString="mongodb+srv://userID:password@clusterTest.mup2u.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Seems like you already understand the principle: it's XML. Therefore certain characters need to be encoded, such as `&` becoming `&amp;` and `<` becoming `&lt;` and `>` becoming `&gt;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're dealing with XML. That means certain characters must be encoded to avoid them being treated as part of the XML structure.

- `&` becomes `&amp;`
- `<` becomes `&lt;`
- `>` becomes `&gt;`